# Wordpress shortcode AMP bind not works

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

I tested on html file and it works.

```
<div hidden
[hidden]="hideGreeting">Hello World</div>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ hideGreeting: false })">Show greeting</button>
<button on='tap:AMP.setState({ text:"testing"})'>Testing Btn</button>
<input type="text" [value]="text1" />
```

[image]

But I added this code as a wordpress shortcode and *[value]* attributes are removed.[image]

Wordpress shortcode function here.
[image]

FYI, First button works but not the second input tag.

Wordpress short code here.

```
function test_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
$html .= '<div><div hidden [hidden]="hideGreeting">Hello World</div><button on="tap:AMP.setState({ hideGreeting: false })">Show greeting</button></div>';               
$html .= '<button on=\'tap:AMP.setState({ text1:"testing"})\'>Testing Btn</button><input type="text" value [value]="text1" />';
return $html;
}
add_shortcode('test_shortcode' , 'test_shortcode_func');
```